# program gives me wrong output for some entries! What's wrong?

Tags: c++

So here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool prime(int);

int main() 
{
    int x;
    cout<<"Enter your number: ";
    cin>>x;
    if(prime(x) == true)
        cout<<"Number is prime";
    if(prime(x) == false)
        cout<<"Number is not prime";
    return 0;
}
bool prime(int number)
{
    for(int i=2; i<number;i++)
    {
        if(number%i==0)
            return false;
        if(number%i!=0)
            return true;
    }
}
```

The program works for all prime numbers (at least for those I tried!) But for some composites, yet is says:Number is not prime!
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Follow the execution of said failed tests with a debugger.

Comment: can you share you fail testcase number

Comment: Isn't it *supposed* to say that a composite number is not prime?

Comment: The `return true;` statement is only valid *after* the loop.  Only then will you have tested all values of `i`.

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated to your specific problem, but wouldn't it be a lot easier to have if(prime(x)) and then a else statement instead of if(prime(x)==false)?

Comment: You didn't manage numbers less than 2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composites are not Prime and all non primes will emit, "Number is not prime"

But you need to modify your code:

```
bool prime(int number)
{
    for(int i=2; i<number;i++)
    {
        if(number%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can only tell if the number is prime after failing all non prime tests

Comment: Note some efficiencies in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20356674/2963099

Answer (score 4):

`prime` function should be as follows

```
bool prime(int number)
{
   for(int i=2; i*i<number;i++) //Only till square root is enough.
   {
       //For any number which is divisible, return false.
       if(number%i==0)
           return false;

   }

   //Else, divisible by no one is prime.
   return true;
```

}

And in this part use else.

```
if(prime(x) == true)
    cout<<"Number is prime";
else
    cout<<"Number is not prime";
```

No need to call the same function twice.